# SQL I want to have a piece deducted from the stock, and in the event that a piece is retrieved it is added to the store

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am using this SQL code but it works on the discount only. I want to make it in the event that a positive value is entered in the sales table, it is deducted from the inventory table, and in the case of entering a negative value, it increases in the inventory table

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TryCutStock_By_Insert] 
ON [dbo].[SaleDetail]
FOR INSERT
AS 
    DECLARE @StockQty AS varchar(10)
    DECLARE @SaleQty AS varchar(10)
    DECLARE @ProID AS varchar(50)
    DECLARE @Result AS varchar(50)

    SELECT @ProID = i.Code FROM inserted i;

    SELECT @StockQty = ItemCard.Qty 
    FROM ItemCard 
    WHERE ItemCard.Code = @ProID;

    SELECT @SaleQty = i.Qty FROM inserted i;

    SELECT
        @Result = CONVERT (int, @StockQty) - CONVERT(int, @SaleQty);

    BEGIN
        UPDATE ItemCard 
        SET Qty = @Result 
        WHERE Code = @ProID;
    END

    PRINT ''
```

Comment: You have posted the expected behaviour of your code. What is the current behaviour? Do you have any concrete examples as to what the differences are between the current and intended behaviour of your code? I don't see any mention of 'discount' in your code either.

Comment: You have tagged your request both MySQL and SQL Server. Is your code supposed to run in both DBMS? They are quite different.

Comment: In the current code you are working on the deduction only from the inventory table. I want to reverse the code in the event that there is a promised on the sales table

Comment: How can I put a reverse condition on this code select @SaleQty =i.Qty from inserted i;

select @Result=CONVERT (int,@StockQty) - CONVERT(int,@SaleQty);

Comment: Or if you have another method that fulfills the requirement other than the one I use currently

Comment: your trigger is not batch aware.

Comment: Please share your table schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: Do NOT attempt to return messages (PRINT) or return resultsets from a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things.

- Don't use VARCHAR datatype for storing integers. Use right datatype.
- As suggested by @Mitch-wheat, design the trigger to be batch aware
- Don't have PRINT statement in the trigger

```sql
begin
update ic
set Qty= CONVERT (int,ic.Qty) - CONVERT(int,i.Qty)
FROM ItemCard AS ic 
INNER JOIN inserted as i
ON i.Code = ic.Code 
end
```

Comment: @AhmedHamed, please mark it as answer. so it is helpful for others in future